# Enabling FTP Server on Mac

Tags: wordpress, ftp

I'm trying to migrate my locally hosted wordpress site to be live and hosted on godaddy. I've never done this before but i'm hung up because my mac ( OS X 10.9.5 ) doesn't have the option to enable an FTP server in the Sharing Preference panel like the tutorials I've been looking at say.

seems like Apple disable the FTP enable button on the fronted

**Question**

Its there a way to enable FTP Servers on mac posterior to Mac 10.0.7?

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the problems is start FTP on MAC Os x 10.7 since Apple disable the option to enable FTP easy on the fronted 
So try this.

**First**

Launch the Terminal `(/Applications/Utilities)` and enter the
    following command to start the FTP server:

```
sudo -s launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist
```

**update**

To test if this works, run

```
$ ftp localhost
```

you should get an output like this.

```
Trying ::1…
Connected to localhost.
220 ::1 FTP server (tnftpd 20100324+GSSAPI) ready.
Name (localhost:Valerie):
```

It’s unclear why Apple pulled the easy frontend to FTP sharing, but if you still want to run a local FTP server (or SFTP) in Mac OS X you can with the help of the command line.

With that you have FTP enable on the mac, and you can keep going into the migrating procces

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I pasted that into to my command line and entered my password when I was prompted. Now what? That didn't make it appear in the frontend. (Sorry I'm really, really new at this)

Comment: No, I am not. I've been looking for tutorials to help with this phase of the migration but all the tutorials I've found deal will older operating systems where the frontend "share files and folders using FTP" is still there. So, I'm unsure on what to do/where to start/what questions to ask.

Comment: how did you paste the $ftp localhost? don't copy/paste just add ftp localhost, without the $ <-- this is from your console on the mac =p

Comment: Just like a note: when you run `sudo -s launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist`, its ask you for the password, because we are using sudo command (super user), so its like authorization prompt don't worry

Comment: sup @Valerie, what you get?

Comment: Ahhh, also new to terminal...thanks for bearing with me. Now I have the correct output. I'm just gonna see how far i can get know before i bug you with more questions.

Answer (score 0):

1- check the owner user of the running httpd apache service (by default _www).. you can use a command like:
ps aux| grep httpd

2- if needed, change the ownership of the Wordpress folder (that contains your wordpress installation) to "_www" user which is the owner user of apache httpd service:

sudo chown -R _www wordpress

sudo chmod -R 755 wordpress